# imap delete email from sent folder

Tags: python, imap

I can not remove email from `Sent` folder. From `Inbox` folder it removes well. I tried with `Sent` and with `[Gmail]/Sent` parameters but it doesn't work. Where it could be the issue?

```
import imaplib

email = "my@gmail.com"
passw = "mypass"
imapserver = "imap.gmail.com"


def deleteEmailIMAP(user, password, IMAP):
    mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP)
    mail.login(user, password)
    mail.select("[Gmail]/Sent")
    typ, data = mail.search(None, 'subject 2f0802e2-e396-4a37-aeae-3a51b6ad288f')
    for num in data[0].split():
        mail.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Deleted)')
    mail.expunge()
    mail.close()
    mail.logout()


deleteEmailIMAP(email, passw, imapserver)
```

logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nikolai/Documents/Python/gmail/test/cv.py", line 23, in <module>
    deleteEmailIMAP(email, passw, imapserver)
  File "/Users/nikolai/Documents/Python/gmail/test/cv.py", line 15, in deleteEmailIMAP
    typ, data = mail.search(None, 'subject 2f0802e2-e396-4a37-aeae-3a51b6ad288f')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 723, in search
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, *criteria)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 1196, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 944, in _command
    ', '.join(Commands[name])))
imaplib.error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

Comment: Is there in fact a mailbox called [Gmail]/Sent?

Comment: Use list() to discover the actual name of the folder. In English, it's usually called `"[Gmail]/Sent Mail"`.  You'll need to quote it if it has a space.

Answer (score 0):

The code does not handle errors. That's why it does not catch server's [tagged `NO` response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.2.2) to the `SELECT` command. It is not visible in the error log, either, but the exception that you've reported means that by the time the code issues `SEARCH`, no mailbox is opened -- and that means that `SELECT` must have failed. (Check the [IMAP protocol states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-3).)

GMail uses localized mailbox names, so the likely culprit is that the user you're authenticating as does not have a mailbox named `[Gmail]/Sent`. If you need to discover the "sent folder" mailbox name, try [RFC 6154](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6154) (or see [Google's docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command)).